# Parse tag name using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, tags

Please help me sir.
How to parse multiple tag using php

```html
<?php
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) 
{ 
$pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/"; 
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches); return $matches[1]; 
}
$str = '<mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid1.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid2.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid3.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid4.mp4</mp4><mp3>hxxps://test.com/music1.mp3</mp3><mp3>hxxps://test.com/music2.mp3</mp3>';
echo getTextBetweenTags($str, "mp4"); // hxxps://test.com/vid4.mp4
?>
```

how to get ouput by list tag from mp4
example :

hxxps://test.com/vid1.mp4

hxxps://test.com/vid2.mp4

hxxps://test.com/vid3.mp4

hxxps://test.com/vid4.mp4

Comment: See [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), when you require more features see [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Answer: `$str = '<mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid1.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid2.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid3.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid4.mp4</mp4><mp3>hxxps://test.com/music1.mp3</mp3><mp3>hxxps://test.com/music2.mp3</mp3>';
print strip_tags(str_replace('><', '>' . PHP_EOL . '<', $str));`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<?php
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) 
{ 
$pattern = "/<{$tagname}>(.*?)<\/{$tagname}>/"; 
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches); return $matches[1]; 
}
$str = '<mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid1.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid2.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid3.mp4</mp4><mp4>hxxps://test.com/vid4.mp4</mp4><mp3>hxxps://test.com/music1.mp3</mp3><mp3>hxxps://test.com/music2.mp3</mp3>';
print_r(getTextBetweenTags($str, "mp4")); // hxxps://test.com/vid4.mp4
?>
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => hxxps://test.com/vid1.mp4
    [1] => hxxps://test.com/vid2.mp4
    [2] => hxxps://test.com/vid3.mp4
    [3] => hxxps://test.com/vid4.mp4
)
```